# Build Error in VB.NET program when MS Office XP is upgraded to MS Office 2007

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.NET 2010 program that works perfectly with MS Office XP. Because of security concerns attributed to Office XP, I recently upgraded to MS Office 2007. I made no changes to the VB program.

A single Build Error, `Type Excel.Global is not defined.` is preventing the program from running. The `ErrorList` points to the `UpgradeSupport` module as the location of the error.

The entire `UpgradeSupport` module is as follows:

```
Module UpgradeSupport
   Friend DAODBEngine_definst As New DAO.DBEngine
   Friend ExcelGlobal_definst As New Excel.[Global]
End Module
```

The instance of `Excel.[Global]` above is the only visible instance of it in the entire program, and there are no instances of `Excel.Global` at all, anywhere. The variable name, `Excel.Global` (or `Excel.[Global]`) suggests a structure. Moreover, I believe `Global` (or `[Global]`) is a property, not a type, and I believe `Excel.Global` and `Excel.[Global]` are not equivalent expressions. I can successfully define structure `Excel.[Global]` as follows:

```
Public Structure Excel
   Shared Property [Global] As Object
End Structure
```

Note: The above will not define successfully without the square brackets around `Global`, which supports my assertion that the two expressions are not equivalent. I question whether any instance of `Type Excel.Global` exists in the program. Nevertheless, the Build Error continues to prevent the program from running. How can I eliminate the Build Error?

Comment: Did you look at this post over at MSDN: [Help: new applications won't build anymore..."Type excel.global not defined"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f88bbacc-a428-485b-8a8f-62328f95d6b5/help-new-applications-wont-build-anymoretype-excelglobal-not-defined?forum=netfxbcl)?

Comment: This issue has been RESOLVED. An automated software update received recently apparently addressed the problem. The UpgradeSupport Module now reads:

Comment: Module UpgradeSupport
 Friend DAODBEngine_definst As New DAO.DBEngine
    Friend ExcelGlobal_definst As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Global
End Module     With that change, the error "Type Excel.Global is not defined" went away.  The program now compiles but still has other issues about which I will deal separately here.